# For which values of reals $ a$ and $ x$ this:${x}^{x^{x^{x^...}}}=a$ could be work?

Tags: convergence-divergence, exponentiation, lambert-w, tetration

What happens to the W-Function in the expression ${x}^{x^{x^{x^...}}}=a$ and what values for $a$ and $x$ they take ? it seems there is a maximum value for $a$ that can take and which?
Really I can't solved it using W-Function

**Note** We may avoid triviality case $x=a=1 $

Comment: Might be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Infinite_heights